# Pangram String Error On My Hackerrank Code

Tags: c++, string, runtime-error

I found [this question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/pangrams/problem) on Hackerrank where I have to write a method to say whether or not a given string is a pangram. A sentence is a pangram if it contains all 26 letters of the alphabet. The input will only contain characters that are alphabetical (uppercase or lowercase) and spaces.

Here's the code I've gotten so far, where I use a set to keep track of which letters are present in the string. However, the code just keeps running infinitely in the while loop below.

```
string pangrams(string s) {
    set<char> set{};
    int i=0;


    while (i!=s.length()) {
        if(s[i]!='\0') {
            set.insert(tolower(s[i]));
        }
    }

    if (set.size() == 27) {
        return "pangram";
    } else {
        return "not pangram";
    }

}
```

Comment: What errors do you get? "code is not working" is insufficient information.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

You're never incrementing i, so your code will run infinitely. I would recommend a for loop `for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i ++)` or a for-each loop `for (char c : s)`

Instead of using a set, you could also try this, where each character corresponds to an index in a `bool[]`

```
bool exists[27];
for (char c : s) {
    if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') {
        exists[c - 'a'] = true;
    } else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'A') {
        exists[c - 'A'] = true;
    } else if (c == ' ') {
        exists[26] = true;
    }
}
for (bool b : exists) {
    if (!b) return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs a slight modification. Firstly, you aren't incrementing `i` which makes your function go into infinite loop. Other modification is explained in code below -

```
string pangrams(string s) {
set<char> set{};
int i=0;


  while (i!=s.length()) {
    if(s[i]!=' ') {           # if character is space, ignore it
        set.insert(tolower(s[i]));
    }
    i++;                      # Main reason of runtime error - you missed incrementing i
  }

   if (set.size() == 26) {    # 26 and not 27. There may be strings without space that are pangrams. So we wont add space into our set.
    return "pangram";
   } else {
    return "not pangram";
  }

}
```

Also, you don't need to check `s[i]!='\0'` since a c++ string isn't terminated with `\0` character. Only checking `i!=s.length()` will be enough.

Hope this clears your issue !

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code causing an infinite loop is that you forgot to increment the value of i inside the while loop. As a result, the loop condition i!=s.length() never becomes false, leading to an infinite loop.

To fix this, you need to add i++ inside the loop to increment the value of i. Here's the corrected code:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

std::string pangrams(const std::string& s) {
    std::set<char> letters{};
    int i = 0;

    while (i != s.length()) {
        if (std::isalpha(s[i])) {
            letters.insert(std::tolower(s[i]));
        }
        i++;  // Increment i
    }

    if (letters.size() == 26) {
        return "pangram";
    } else {
        return "not pangram";
    }
}
```

In this code, std::isalpha() function from the  header is used to check if a character is alphabetic. Also, I recommend using a more descriptive name than set for the set variable to avoid conflicts with the std::set class name.